# own library with global tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, window, global

I want to create a library that modify the tkinter window i created in a script.
I want it in a library in order my main script not to be too big, but when i call my library, well, it doesn't work.

```
Here is the main script:
import my_lib
from tkinter import *

global my_window
my_window = Tk()

global my_button
my_button = Button(my_window, "This is a button", command = my_lib.menu)
```

and the library:

```
def menu():
    my_button.destroy()

    global menu_button
    menu_button = Button(my_window, "Button", command = print("You hit the button"))
```

By launching the main script I get the following error:

```
File "main_script.py, line 8, in <module>
 my_button = Button(my_window, "This is a button", command = my_lib.menu)
File "C:\\Program Files\Pytonh 3.4\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2192, in __init__
  Widget.__init__(selfn master, 'button', cnf, kw)
File "C:\\Program Files\Pytonh 3.4\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2113, in __init__
  cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
File "C:\\Program Files\Pytonh 3.4\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 105, in _cnfmerge
  cnf.update(c)
ValueError: dictionnary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Comment: First of all, I don't see why you are trying to put just a few lines of code in another separate file. The traceback is clearly saying where is the error: `my_button = Button(my_window, "This is a button", command = my_lib.menu)`. You need to specify the attribute when setting its value. You are trying to set the attribute `text` of your buttons, but you are not specifying it. You need to do something like `text="This is a button"`

Comment: Yes I got the answer from Eric, sorry it's a beginner's mistake. Shame on me.
As for the length of the script this is of course only an shortened example of my real script. The library contains over 50 functions, and the main script is around 300 lines long (if I had to merge the two, that would begin to be a little long to work on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
my_button = Button(my_window, "This is a button", command = my_lib.menu)
```

by:

```
my_button = Button(my_window, text="This is a button", command = my_lib.menu)
```

(and the same in your "lib" -in python module is the usual term)

See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#Tkinter.Button-class
for Button documentation.